# boost::shared_ptr drop-in replacement

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Recently i started to work on one legacy project and trying to fix segfaults (double delete). Many of them is happening on `boost::shared_ptr` destructor or `operator=`(on objects that contain a shared_ptr). The code contains is massive usage of shared_ptr-s, including copying, reset()-ing, assigning etc. According to [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety) we have not valid usage - its not safe to destruct/copy/reset same shared_ptr in many threads.

Locking each time seems impossible, so im searching for drop-in replacement for boost::shared_ptr. So the question is: if i replace all `boost::shared_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` will the solve this issue? Seems tr1 is safer version but its not clear for me. Second question - is c++0x version any better than tr1 ? (note we have gcc 4.4.6 and cannot upgrade it)

Accoring to [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#id486672), c++11 std::shared_ptr should fix that, but im not sure about gcc4.4 version...

UPD: Just maked experiment and now i know all 3 implementations do segfault on this code(gcc 4.4).. seems i should make custom class or maybe other workaround...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> ptrtype;

ptrtype p(new int);

void test() {
        for(long i=0; i<1000000; ++i) {
                ptrtype p1 = p;
                p = ptrtype();
                p.reset( new int );
        }
}

int main() {
        boost::thread_group tg;
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) tg.add_thread( new boost::thread(test) );
        tg.join_all();
        std::cout << "Normal exit\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: boost::shared_ptr is quite solid.  I don't think that replacing it with another implementation is going to 'solve' anything.  If you're seeing double deletes, then you will continue to see these until you find and fix your bugs.

Comment: The "locking each time seems impossible" indicates you have threading issues. Changing the smart pointer implementation is not going to buy you anything. boost::shared_ptr is not buggy.

Comment: Are you looking for a thread-safe shared pointer?

Comment: Im not saying its buggy. Our code is buggy, it uses shared_ptr in manner that marked as "undefined behaviour" in boost docs. (updated the asnwer with link)

Comment: I doubt changing the particular shared_ptr will fix your code.

Comment: At the moment i want to remove segfaults, its not time to make refactoring for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Yakk no, i have 30segfaults per day xD

Comment: It strikes me that if your code's use of `boost::shared_ptr` isn't thread-safe,  this will be the least of your worries: there will be many more subtle threading issues to be dealt with.

Comment: @Marko at the moment project working under load and has no other serious bugs. Seems guy who wrote shared_ptr everywhere didnt know that he cannot just reset.. or just copy... But its strange to me too: if shared_ptr promise to deal with **delete** - why he is not doing that properly? Its strange to declare: "`operator=` is thread-safe .. unless other thread is doing [insert method]"

Comment: What you're doing is undefined behaviour with `boost::shared_ptr` and also with `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, switching to one of them won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Build a class like this, and replace usage of `boost::shared_ptr<T>` with it.

```
template<typename T>
struct trivial_ptr {
  T* t;
  template<typename U>
  void reset( U* p ) {t=p;}
  void reset( T* p = NULL ) { t=p; }
  template<typename U>
  trivial_ptr<T>& operator=(trivial_shared_ptr<U>const& o) {
    t = o.t;
    return *t;
  }
  explicit trivial_ptr( T* p ):t(p) {}
  ...
};
```

this class is not intended to run, but just to compile with the correct interface.  Once you have compiled, you can ensure you know what parts of the `boost::shared_ptr` interface you are using.  (Are you using custom deleters?  etc -- the problem could be harder, or easier, and the above can help test it)

Once you are there, you can work out how hard it will be to write up a `shared_ptr<T>` that handles multiple threads accessing the same variable at the same time.

Now, this is extremely messy.  If one thread `reset`s a given `shared_ptr` while another thread reads from it, the pointer read from *may be completely invalid* by the time the reading thread has access to it.  In effect, you need to guard *all* access to the underlying pointer in a mutex, which is utterly impractical.

On the other hand, if what you have is multiple readers, and never a reader and a writer, you are in better shape -- in theory, you could fix the problem with the use of appropriate locks on the reference count code.

However, what you actually describe seems to involve multiple threads both reading and writing to the same variable.  And that is fundamentally broken in a way that mere thread safety on the `shared_ptr` variable is not going to fix.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Probably i should switch to custom class.. My experiment showing all 3 standard implementations fail this use case(

Comment: @PSIAlt: Did you not read his last paragraph? You can't fix the problem by creating a new pointer type. Not unless you're going to mutex-wrap every pointer instance, and even then, you'll still have problems because someone is going to assume that the old pointer was around. You cannot escape the fact that you have been handed a horrifically buggy codebase and you need to fix it.

Comment: @NicolBolas ugh, seems really there is no other way than.. dunno what yet.. It looks like i have no chance to rewrite this without broking something. But, thanks for pointing about locking

Answer (score 1):

The problem you appear to have is attempting to modify the same instance of a variable in two separate threads (AKA a data race).   shared_ptr is no more protected against this than int's are.  Your reference to the gcc docs says the same thing ("same level of thread safety as built-in types").  Attempting to modify the same instance of a shared_ptr in two different threads requires some sort of synchronization to prevent the data race.  Attempting to modify two different instances of a shared_ptr that are pointing to the same object is OK (no data race, or shared_ptr must implement whatever is necessary to prevent a data race internally).  Attempting to modify the object that they point to is also a data race.

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr` *may* use atomic ints if the compiler/architecture/implementation supports/use it. But i wouldn't bet on it, and doing so will make your code less portable. But it may work as a temporary workaround (e.g. to have a running program so you understand what the code is supposed to do).

Writing your own `shared_ptr` wrapper might be an option, but your code will still need to be audited for deadlocks.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is required to be thread-safe... but *only* as thread-safe as `boost::shared_ptr`. That is, two different shared_ptr objects can be referring to the same data, and deleting will be fine. But you can't poke at the *same* shared_ptr object from two different threads. The latter is the problem the OP has.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is **required** to be thread-safe, but only for copying instances concurrently, not modifying them concurrently